# How to change the variable when click and pass it to another activity in android (There is a code)?

Tags: java, android, variables, android-activity

I want to change (int A1) to [(int A1) = (A1 +1)] when user click on radiobutton pic1radioA
 and pass the variable value to another activity 
and change it again onclick and so on on the five radiobuttons and five variables.

but with this code my app crashes when i click on radiobutton and i get :
java.lang.RuntimeException & java.lang.nullpointerexception .

Help Please ..

This is The Activity1 Code :

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    RadioButton pic1radioA;
    RadioButton pic1radioB;
    RadioButton pic1radioC;
    RadioButton pic1radioD;
    RadioButton pic1radioE;
    Button button1;

    int A1;
    int B1;
    int C1;
    int D1;
    int E1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity1);

        pic1radioA = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.pic1radioA);
        pic1radioB = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.pic1radioB);
        pic1radioC = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.pic1radioC);
        pic1radioD = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.pic1radioD);
        pic1radioE = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.pic1radioE);

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        pic1radioA.setOnClickListener(this);
        pic1radioB.setOnClickListener(this);
        pic1radioC.setOnClickListener(this);
        pic1radioD.setOnClickListener(this);
        pic1radioE.setOnClickListener(this);

        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity1, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch(v.getId()){

          case R.id.pic1radioA:
               Intent iA1 = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
               iA1.putExtra("A1",A1 +1);
               startActivity(iA1);
               break;
          case R.id.pic1radioB:
               Intent iB1 = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
               iB1.putExtra("B1",B1 +1);
               startActivity(iB1);
               break;
          case R.id.pic1radioC:
               Intent iC1 = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
               iC1.putExtra("C1",C1 +1);
               startActivity(iC1);
               break;
          case R.id.pic1radioD:
               Intent iD1 = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
               iD1.putExtra("D1",D1 +1);
               startActivity(iD1);
               break;
          case R.id.pic1radioE:
               Intent iE1 = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
               iE1.putExtra("E1",E1 +1);
               startActivity(iE1);
               break;
          case R.id.button1:
               Intent intentF1 = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
               startActivity(intentF1);
               break;
          }

    }




}
```

This is The Activity2 Code :

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    RadioButton pic2radioA;
    RadioButton pic2radioB;
    RadioButton pic2radioC;
    RadioButton pic2radioD;
    RadioButton pic2radioE;
    Button button2;

    int A2 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("A1");
    int B2 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("B1");
    int C2 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("C1");
    int D2 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("D1");
    int E2 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("E1");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity2);

        pic2radioA = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.pic2radioA);
        pic2radioB = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.pic2radioB);
        pic2radioC = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.pic2radioC);
        pic2radioD = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.pic2radioD);
        pic2radioE = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.pic2radioE);

        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        pic2radioA.setOnClickListener(this);
        pic2radioB.setOnClickListener(this);
        pic2radioC.setOnClickListener(this);
        pic2radioD.setOnClickListener(this);
        pic2radioE.setOnClickListener(this);

        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity2, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){

          case R.id.pic2radioA:
               Intent iA2 = new Intent(this, Activity3.class);
               iA2.putExtra("A2",A2 +1);
               startActivity(iA2);
               break;
          case R.id.pic2radioB:
               Intent iB2 = new Intent(this, Activity3.class);
               iB2.putExtra("B2",B2 +1);
               startActivity(iB2);
               break;
          case R.id.pic2radioC:
               Intent iC2 = new Intent(this, Activity3.class);
               iC2.putExtra("C2",C2 +1);
               startActivity(iC2);
               break;
          case R.id.pic2radioD:
               Intent iD2 = new Intent(this, Activity3.class);
               iD2.putExtra("D2",D2 +1);
               startActivity(iD2);
               break;
          case R.id.pic2radioE:
               Intent iE2 = new Intent(this, Activity3.class);
               iE2.putExtra("E2",E2 +1);
               startActivity(iE2);
               break;
          case R.id.button2:
               Intent intentF2 = new Intent(this, Activity3.class);
               startActivity(intentF2);
               break;
          }

    }

}
```

Comment: post the manifest file and the stacktrace.

Comment: when i moved getIntent().getExtras().getInt() to the onCreate he told me on the onclick method A2 cannot be reesolved to a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ado this :

```
    int A2;
    int B2;
    int C2;
    int D2;
    int E2;
```

And in `onCreate`:

```
    A2 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("A1");
    B2 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("B1");
    C2 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("C1");
    D2 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("D1");
    E2 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("E1");
```

`getIntent()` is not available before onCreate is called.

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
RadioButton pic2radioA;
RadioButton pic2radioB;
RadioButton pic2radioC;
RadioButton pic2radioD;
RadioButton pic2radioE;
Button button2;

  int A2;
    int B2;
    int C2;
    int D2;
    int E2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity2);
    A2 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("A1");
    B2 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("B1");
    C2 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("C1");
    D2 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("D1");
    E2 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("E1");

    .......rest of the code.

 }
```

onClick:

```
  @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){

          case R.id.pic2radioA:
               Intent iA2 = new Intent(this, Activity3.class);
               A2=A2+1;
               iA2.putExtra("A2",A2);
               startActivity(iA2);
               break;
      //same for the rest
     }}
```

Comment: when i moved getIntent().getExtras().getInt() to the onCreate he told me on the onclick method A2 cannot be reesolved to a variable

Comment: this is why i wrote to declare all int variables in Activity not in on create.

Comment: Thanks it worked ..
I am sorry for bothering you, but when i finally get the value of value it dosent count properly !
Is there something wrong with the logic or the code ?

Thank you so much ..,

Comment: in onClick write A2=A2+1; iA2.putExtra("A2",A2); same for the rest

Comment: It didn't count properly same as before :( , i forgot to tell you that i have 12 activity 11 like activity 2 & 1 for the result and it count wrong when i click at different button each time , and right when i click on the same button .. help please

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't call getIntent().getExtras().getInt() in the variable list. As far as I know, the Intent isn't yet available at that time. Try moving it to the onCreate method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity2);

    int A2 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("A1");
    int B2 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("B1");
    int C2 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("C1");
    int D2 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("D1");
    int E2 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("E1");

    /* Rest of the code */
}
```

Comment: when i moved getIntent().getExtras().getInt() to the onCreate he told me on the onclick method A2 cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: @user3199244 before onCreate `int A2;` then in onCreate  `A2 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("A1");`